# very new to java and facing Whitelabel Error Page

Tags: java, jar, cmd

I have backed jar files and I`m trying to run them on localhost after typing command java -jar backend.jar after directing to backend.jar path ,please help how to fix this error and run file
the error syntex:
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri May 08 15:37:40 PDT 2015
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

Comment: Is backend.jar a webserver? What does *directing to backend.jar path* mean?

Comment: I`m not sure Iwas following readme file, about backend.jar contains xml file and meta-inf and folder contains class files and controller

Comment: Yes ... but >>what it is<<?

Comment: it is a backend java files for app

Comment: And where did you get it from?

Comment: it is a test from my college

Comment: Do you have any fellow classmates you can discuss it with? Or a TA?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this "backend.jar" file uses Spring Boot, and for some reason you are getting the so-called "Whitelabel Error page" ... as described [in the Spring Boot documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#spring-boot-and-error-handling).

If you read the above, it explains that this is the default error page that you get if a "nice" error page has not been configured.  If you wanted to make it nice, the documentation explains how to do it.

However, I suspect that you *really* want to find out what is causing you to go to the error page.

- Check the log files created by the "backend.jar" application.  Look for clues; e.g. a Java stack trace, or a more specific error message.
- If there is nothing useful in the logfiles, figure out how and where the logging levels are set, and increase them so that you get debug level logging.  Then try again.
- Reread the README file and check that you have done it correctly.
- Ask your teacher ...